# Snapping a div to a fixed navigation bar on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to make a web responsive page and and my problem is snapping a div to a fixed navigation bar when I scroll down the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/56jkmvma/1/

Depending on the window size or zoom, the div will either overshoot or undershoot the navigation bar.

My best attempt was to use scrollTop() to prevent further page scrolling once the scrollTop(value) matched the value where the content-div meets the nav bar, but it only worked for 100% zoom and hard coded values.

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  var navHeight = $('.nav').height();
  var stopPoint = winHeight - navHeight;// gives position where scrollTop should stop allowing the div to 'snap' to the nav bar
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollPos == stopPoint) {
   $(window).scrollTop(stopPoint);
  }
});
```

I've also tried to use anchors and scrollTo(), but never got one working correctly. Open to any methods, Thanks!

Comment: So the moment you scroll it should snap to and stay connected to the nav bar? And it unsnaps once you scroll back to the top?

Comment: Yes it should snap once it reaches the nav bar and also unsnap when you scroll in the other direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you are looking for something like this [Example](http://jsbin.com/cejoji/edit?css,js,output)

and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var heightNav=$('.nav').height();
  var posCon=$('.content').offset().top;
  var posWin;
  $(window).on('scroll',function(){
   posWin=$(this).scrollTop()+heightNav;

    if(posWin >  posCon){
      $('.content').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: heightNav,
        'margin-top':0

      });

    } 

    else {
      $('.content').css({
        position: 'relative',
        'margin-top':'20em',
        top:0

      });
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: One important thing to mention about your solution is that it effectively takes the content out of the normal document flow, which would have normally caused the `body` height to shrink to nothing. You overcame that by giving the `body` a fixed height in your JSBin example.

Comment: @NanoWizard Yes, that was only for `scroll` demonstration. Edited bin and added `min-height` to `body`

Comment: @itsgoingdown Awesome!!! I had to double heightNav because it was only snapping after I scrolled past the nav, but now it works like a charm